# Android DialogFragment вылетает из за setTitle

Tags: java, android

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
        getDialog().setTitle(getString(R.string.date_picker_title));


        mDatePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day,null);
        v.findViewById(R.id.ok_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;

    }




     //Создание фрагмента
     public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);
    DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    datePickerFragment.setArguments(args);
    return datePickerFragment;
}
```

Comment: LogCat с ошибкой покажите

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.criminalintent.DatePickerFragment.onCreateView(DatePickerFragment.java:52)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)

Comment: это`getString(R.string.date_picker_title)` попробуйте через `getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string. date_picker_title);`, плюс смущает немного getDialog()

Comment: @Andrew, диалога нет. Со строкой все в порядке. Автор, добавьте в вопрос код как вы фрагмент создаете.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, вроде ж все происходит в DialogFragment, вот и подумал что все-таки получение ресурса может барахлить

Comment: добавил создание фрагмента

Comment: Это не то - интересует как вы его показываете: как диалог или как обычный фрагмент. `getDialog()` работает только после создания диалога (`onCreateDialog()`), а он создаётся только если фрагмент показан вызовом `DialogFragment.show()`

Comment: Fragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment(); вы об этом?

Comment: у вас есть два места в программе - где создается и вызывается ваш диалог, и собственное сам диалог где у вас беда, как уже сказал @woesss, создание вашего диалога малоинтересно, больше интересует как вы на него попадаете, то есть например нажали на кнопку и ждете что вот ваш диалог появится, или типа такого, посмотрите где в коде происходит вызов `.show()`

Comment: как фрагмент у которого отдельная активность выступает хостом

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку Intent intent = DatePickerActivity.newIntent(getActivity(),mCrime.getDate());
                startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_DATE);

Comment: Тогда у него нет диалога - это обычный фрагмент и заголовок вы можете установить только в экшн-бар активности (если он там есть), или в тулбар, добавленный непосредственно в разметку фрагмента